# SMB stops working periodically

Tags: smbclient

my Windows Server 2016 Remote Desktop Servers SMB client, randomly stops working for 1 to 10 minutes, then restarts with no user intervention.
The Windows SMBClient event log marks the problem with events 30805 and 30807 upon disconnection. Events 30806 and 30808 are fired when the service comes back on.

In the fault interval:

- I *can* PING my fileservers / NAS
- I cannot browse SMB shares using Windows Explorer (using \fileserver or \ip_address). I get a waiting cursor and a blank window.
- net view \fileserver (or net view \ip_address) given from a command line just waits with no result.

The problem is not related to a single RD server, as it shows on all of them *at different times*

Thanks in advance for any suggestion!